Rendering issue with ttk.TreeView
I'm trying to use the ttk treeview widget.  I'm able to create and populate it, and it seems to work properly.  However it is rendering with a large empty "column" on the left side and I can't figure out what is causing it.  I've verified that column(0) is the first column I defined so don't know where this is coming from.  Code to create the treeview:
cols = ("EIR", "Env", "Name", "Function", "IP", "Model")
col_widths = (75, 50, 120, 150, 100, 150)
self.tv = tv = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=cols)
for col, col_w in zip(cols, col_widths):
  tv.column(column=col, width=col_w, anchor=tk.W)
  tv.heading(column=col, text=col, anchor=tk.W)

Rendered treeview:


Try adding
self.tv = tv = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=cols)
self.tv["show"] = "headings"  # <- Added line


Issue solved by adding show='headings' to initial load:
self.tv = tv = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=cols, show='headings')

